# Stof Doctrine Extensions bundle

Tags: symfony1, doctrine-orm, vendor

I have something weird going on when I'm trying to setup the Doctrine Extensions and the Stof Doctrine Extensions bundle. After I followed the tutorial by Stof, I get an error that he doesn't know stof_doctrine_extensions in the config.yml. Also in the list of namespaces he doesn't exist (that the terminal shows on that kind of error).

Does somebody got the same problem? Do I need a specific branch... I'm using Symfony 2.0.x with Doctrine 2.1.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to Symfony 2.1.* for this bundle to work.

https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#bring-in-the-vendor-libraries

Comment: I have been using this bundle with 2.0.x for several months - so it definitely can work.

Comment: Just checked my deps.lock - as of a couple of weeks ago, I was running this version: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/tree/f141a698d65271a18d86469c1f7b29d7e24170dd with sf 2.0.15